# Is sbt.boot.properties used in sbt 0.10+?

Tags: scala, sbt

pre-sbt `0.10.0` used an `sbt.boot.properties` to define sbt's boot configuration file.

What is the sbt 0.10.0 "way" of defining boot properties?

I am looking for the equivalent of `sbt.boot.properties` (not `build.properties`) that's activated by `-Dsbt.boot.properties=...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sbt.boot.properties` exists in `0.10` (up to and including `0.13.1` that's the latest version of sbt at the moment) and is essentially the same [as before](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Launcher).

The main addition is that the [default sbt.boot.properties](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/launch/src/main/input_resources/sbt/sbt.boot.properties) is set up to allow a few properties to be defined by system properties.  This can avoid the need to use a custom `sbt.boot.properties` in some common cases.

The two main properties configurable in this way are defined by the following sections of the default file:

```
[boot]
  directory: ${sbt.boot.directory-project/boot/}

[ivy]
  ivy-home: ${sbt.ivy.home-${user.home}/.ivy2/}
```

The syntax for variables is bash-like: `${system.property.name-default}`.  This means that you can set the boot directory with something like:

```
$ sbt -Dsbt.boot.directory=/home/user/.sbt/boot/
```

If unspecified, it would default to `project/boot/` as usual.  Similarly, you can set the Ivy home directory with:

```
$ sbt -Dsbt.ivy.home=/home/user/.sbt/.ivy2/
```

If unspecified, it defaults to the usual `.ivy2` subdirectory in the directory defined by the `user.home` system property.